# Plone: Link Integrity not working

Tags: plone, zope

UPDATE: Actually there is no bug?   The feature we should be using is Link by UID and not Link Integrity.  If we enable Link by UID in TinyMCE, we can move folders anywhere without the links breaking.

UPDATE:  This is a Plone bug.  We tested on a fresh new Plone installation and confirmed that link integrity breaks down in the following scenario:

When you insert images or attach files in a page and these images and files are in the same folder as the page folder or in another folder inside the same top level parent folder as the page folder, the links will not be preserved when you move this page to another folder outside the parent folder or to another folder within the parent folder but on a different level as to the page folder.   That is, the images and files in the page will be preserved only when you move the move to another folder which is inside the same parent folder as the page AND on the same level relative to the parent folder.

When you insert images or attache files in a page and these images and files are from a folder outside the top-level parent folder of the page, these images and files in the  page are preserved when you move the page to another folder.

That is, it is not advisable to upload images and files to a folder inside the same top-level parent folder as the page when you will be attaching the files/images it -- because you cannot move this page to another folder (except same level same top-level parent) without breaking the image and file attachments in the page.

======
We are using Plone 4.1.3, and having problem with preserving links when moving a page from one folder to another.    That is, Link Integrity isn't working even though it is enabled in our Site Setup's Editor Settings (TinyMCE - Enable link integrity checks).    Our understanding of link integrity is that we should be able to move a page to another folder and the images and file attachments in the page should still work.   This is what we desire.     However, now when we move the page to another folder, the URL of the image or file attachment in the page stays the same, i.e., a relative URL, e.g. ../../folder-xxx/xxx.jpg.   So the URL will only work if we move to a folder which is on the same level relative to the same parent top-level folder.   It won't work if we move the page to a folder on another level or to a folder outside the top-level folder -- because the URL doesn't change.

We don't really know when this problem started.  It could have started when we upgraded from Plone 4.1.2 to Plone 4.1.3.   But we are not sure.     When we upgraded, we did a fresh install and copied the blobstorage and filestorage over.  I think everything was fine after the upgrade, so we are really at a loss on what happened.   We think we were able to move pages with the links preserved in the past.

Is there a setting in ZMI on Plone Site Setup for Link Integrity (other than Editor Settings)?

Please advise.

Thank you very much in anticipation.

cmgui

Comment: That is odd and must be a bug. FWIW, I always use links with UIDs. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.outputfilters will then transform the resolveuid/UID into full urls.

Comment: Hm. I don't think TMCE should be putting relative links there in the first place. If you want to debug in a copy of your site, go to ZMI, portal_transforms, policy, and remove the rule(s) involving plone.outputfilter. (Target mimetype x-safe-html, IIRC). Then, you should see .../resolveuid/.... links in the page.

Comment: Thank you Vangheem but I don't know what UIDs are. Are they something Kupu uses?   We are using TinyMCE.

Comment: Thank you Ulrich.  I tried what you suggested.  After removing text/x-html-safe (output type) / html_to_plone_outputfilters_html (use transforms), we get the actual folder name instead of folder-xxxx.  So removing html_to_plone_outputfilters_html seems to undo the 'UIDs'?

Comment: Ulrich, correction, removing html_to_plone_outputfilters_html didn't make any difference at all.   Somehow for some folders where we stored our images, when we insert a link in a page pointing to an image or file in the folder, the folder appears as folder-xxxx in the URL.  For some folders, the actual folder name appears.  Strange.

Comment: Okay, actually this problem happens only when the file/image attachment is from within the same parent folder as the page.   When we move this page to anywhere, such link will break.   But when we attach a file or image that is located outside the parent folder of the page, the link still works when we move the page.    There is also another strange thing, sometimes, the folder name in the link changes to folder-xxx-xxx when xxx is some number, but sometimes, the folder name remains unchanged.

Comment: Hi Ulrich and Vangheem.   We have confirmed that this is a Plone bug.   See update in the post.   Do you know the best practice on where to store images and files in Plone?   Thank you.

Comment: link using UID. It's an option in tinymce configuration. Every object has a UID assigned to it so it's a safe way to link objects on your site.